# what type of display does a normal caculator have?

Tags: display

What type of display does a normal calculator have? Normal means which is not so functional like scientific calculation. Basically I want to know what is that which shows black digits  on display?  I dissembled one calculator and saw its display was almost transparent. I did not get its functionality. Can someone explain it.

Thanks!!
In advance.

Comment: That's an [LCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing something called a *liquid crystal display*, usually just called LCD.

The main advantage of these displays is that they are very low power.